# Get the correct order of elements with id and previous element-id

Tags: mysql

I want to get a result in a correct order. Each row of a table got the row-ID and the ID of the previous element, so there should be a clear order

**SQL-Table**:

```
id|prev
1|0
2|1
3|2
```

I thought a simple

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY prev ASC
```

should work. But if I'll add, remove and edit some informations, the table could look like this:

```
id|prev
1|0
2|1
3|2
4|6
5|4
6|3
```

Still there is a clear order, but the above Select-statement doesn't work, as element 6 is set to be right between element 3 and 4.

I don't know how to get the correct order of the results in SQL, which should be 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5 in this example.

Comment: You should just drop this approach and replace `prev` with a `sortorder` int field which can be regenerated as modifications require.

Comment: Ok. I just tried this because I only have to change one element, when adding a new row in between (just modifying a single pre-value). When using a sort order-field I have to modify ALL following  rows...

Comment: this would be a CONNECT BY hierarchic query in those databases that support it.  maybe this will help your search for mysql implementations

Comment: `update table set sortorder = sortorder + 1 where sortorder > newsortorder` isn't an expensive operation. Your approach could work, but it's optimal only for very limited use cases, and probably beyond overkill for yours.